# vimscript delete whole line or word in command mode (q:)

Tags: command-line, vim, vimrc

I'm trying to figure out how to delete a whole line in command mode.  I see lots of example .vimrc's with:

```
cnoremap <C-a>  <Home>
cnoremap <C-b>  <Left>
cnoremap <C-f>  <Right>
cnoremap <C-d>  <Delete>
cnoremap <M-b>  <S-Left>
cnoremap <M-f>  <S-Right>
" This doesn't delete a word as I'd expect
cnoremap <M-d>  <S-Right><Delete>
```

All of these work as expected with exception of `<M-d>`.  I'd expect that do delete a whole word, but it just jumps to the end and deletes a single character.  Is there a `<Delete Word>` or `<Delete Line>`?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't reflect its content. Do you want to delete the whole line or a whole word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the command-line (like in insert mode), the command for deleting a whole word backward is `<C-w>` and the one for deleting the whole line until the cursor is `<C-u>`. They are not that hard to type so I don't think you should remap them at all. Anyway…

```
"delete word, backward
cnoremap <M-d> <C-w>

"delete word, forward
cnoremap <M-d> <S-Right><C-w>
```

But, if you do a lot of editing on the command-line, you should look into the command-line window: press `<C-f>` to edit the current command or `q:` to open the command-line window directly.

```
:help cmdline-widow
:help cmdline-editing
```

Comment: Thanks!  The reason for remap is I use those motions everywhere.  It's very hard to overcome muscle memory for one instance.  I use q: for bigger changes but opening it for one word change seems silly.

Comment: Also where is the list of all the abbreviations for those in vimscript?

Comment: See `:viusage`.

Comment: if the command line is `abc/def`, the cursor is on `a`, with `<S-Right><C-w>`, the command line becomes `abc/`, but I am expecting `/def`, seems the two commands have a different definition of "word".